# About quadratic residue modular p(p is prime)

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

The question is this.

> Suppose that p is a prime, $p\ge7$. Show that $(\frac np)=(\frac {n+1}p)=1$ for at least one number n in the set {1,2,...,9}.

I think seperating into two cases when n=1 and when n=4 will help me prove it. But I can't think further...

Plz, HELP ME!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the statement is not true. We clearly have $\left(\frac{1}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{4}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{9}{p}\right) = 1$. By assumption we must then have $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{10}{p}\right) = -1$. Can you derive a contradiction from this?

Comment: Hmm, then (10/p)=(2/p)*(5/p)=(-1)*(-1)=1 which is a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Wow!!! I never thought of that!! Thank you!!!!